# KeystoneJs virtual field cannot use a custom field type

Tags: keystonejs

I need to display a json/object in a readonly form and I wrote a custom field type for it but then when I use a virtual to transform it to a string for passing it to the custom field type. I put the custom type into the args but it shows  `Error: Unknown type "JsonViewer".`

Any idea of how to make it work?

```
const { Virtual } = require("@keystonejs/fields");
const JsonViewer = require("@/components/fields/jsonViewer");

module.exports = {
  fields: {
    requestData: {
      type: Virtual,
      args: [{ name: "requestData", type: "JsonViewer" }],
      resolver: async (json) => {
        return JSON.stringify(json);
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide complex type details if they do not exist in the generated schema for graphql.

In your case as you are doing `JSON.stringify` you can use `String` return type like this. BTW `String` type is default return type and you should not need any type declaration there for string type.

Also there is no `args` option in keystone Virtual field.

```
const { Virtual } = require("@keystonejs/fields");

module.exports = {
  fields: {
    requestData: {
      type: Virtual,
      graphQLReturnType: `String`,
      resolver: async (json) => {
        return JSON.stringify(json);
      },
    },
  }
}
```